# Getting image on plotly graph to be sharp

Tags: python, image, plotly, data-visualization, plotly-python

I am struggling to add a logo to an image without it coming out blurry. I am using chrome and python. See my code below.

Note: I think the answer might have to do with Plotly doing *pixel smoothing* per this post [here](https://community.plotly.com/t/rendering-of-images-in-dash-plotly/15305), unfortunately I don't know how to implement this in jupyter notebook or what an assets directory is and such!

I have tried encoding it and resizing it a million times. I have also tried both SVG and PNG. Random luck seems to have it sometimes better shrpness, but otherwise I am clueless. The image is 415 by 100, though I have tried varying the image sizes...

```
included = relevant_df

fig = px.line(included,
            x='date', y='contri_1yr_qual', color='url_short', 
            hover_data=["id", "createdAt", 'first_inst'],
            category_orders={"url_short": list(included.url_short[:20])})

        
fig.update_layout(title={
        'text': "Active Qualified Contributors Over Time - SRE stack",
        'y':0.95,
        'x':0.5,
        'xanchor': 'center',
        'yanchor': 'top'}, width=1000, height=600)

# ------- THIS IS THE PROBLEM BELOW
fig.add_layout_image(
    dict(
        source='rajko_sig2.svg',
        xref="paper", yref="paper",
        x=0.02, y=0.8,
        sizex=0.4, sizey=0.5,
        sizing = 'contain',
        xanchor="left", yanchor="bottom"
    )
)


fig.show()
```

Comment: Would it be the same on a higher scale?

Comment: sorry, I don't follow, what do you mean by 'on a higher scale'?

Comment: It means to increase the scale value. `scale=3`?[https://plotly.com/python/static-image-export/#change-image-dimensions-and-scale](https://plotly.com/python/static-image-export/#change-image-dimensions-and-scale)

Comment: ah, got it, thank you! I am trying to import/add a photo to a plot, not export an image, so i only have these options: https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/images/, scale isn't one of them :/

Comment: I see what was confusing, I had commented out an export option, sorry, the image export is fine, the issue is with the "add_layout_image" line... clarifying that now!!

Comment: I tried to import the stackoverflow logo using url or localsave, but it didn't work. I'm guessing that SVG is the issue, but if you convert the SVG file to PNG, will that make a difference?

Comment: yeah, no difference using SVG or PNG :/